# Confusion over the word "between"

Tags: differences

I recently heard someone say 'between he and I there's difference'
Is it correct not to use him and me?

Comment: Idiomatically the phrase is usually *between him and me*.

Answer (score 0):

Because *between* is a preposition one must always use *him and me.* In my
experience, this is the most common mistake made by English speakers, who too often use *I* when it should be *me*, such as in:

- Nothing should ever come between you and *I.

(Or, as in the example given by the asker, the use of *he* instead of *him*.)

That should be:

- Nothing should ever come between you and me.

These mistakes occur in every walk of life including (most especially) TV
journalists who should know better. Generally, the test is to eliminate one
of the two objects, which makes the error much more obvious as in:

- Nothing should ever come between *I.
- Nothing should come between *he.

Comment: All this is true, but the very same question has been asked many times before. If you have something new to add, please add a new answer to the "original", not to the new duplicate.